# Will I lose My files on Drive (D:)? Reinstalling windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive

I am Currently Reinstalling windows7 32bit to 64bit. But i am not sure if my hard drives will get deleted. I have 3 hard drives.

(C:) Full Of Programs.
(D:) Important files and movies. 
(G:) System Reserved

Now Im asking Will Drive (D:) get its data erased? If so Can I safely install windows7 64bit without the data Of Drive (D:) being erased?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Make a full backup of your important files before make a clean install, take a look: http://www.windowscentral.com/how-upgrade-32-bit-64-bit-version-windows-10

Comment: During a Windows installation, it is possible to select options that will cause you to loose your data. If you do everything correctly, you will not loose your data. But, given that it's clear you are not an experienced user, the risk of data-loss is there. You should have a backup of your data in either case, but considering this risk, you should *realy* have a backup...

Answer (score 2):

It always depends on where your system is installed.

If D: is another hard disk (or whatever other data storage hardware) just unplug to perform a safety reinstallation.

If D: is a partition of a unique hardware, be careful. You should only format the partition/drive that your system is installed. Paying attention on the information given at the install screens and you will let your D: drive (or partition) as it is.

Comment: +1 for recommending that you unplug the hard drive (if possible). It's the easiest way to avoid accidentally installing Windows to the wrong disk.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, if you are installing OS on your drive D: you have 2 options :

1- Is to wipe your disk ( format ) it will delete anything on the disk and installs windows .

2- You can just install windows on drive D: without losing any data ( If you chose not to format or wipe the drive ) , it will install windows and all its content on the drive if there is enough disk space .

Usually by default your OS is installed on C: .

My suggestion to you is to backup your important files / Videos  from C: to D: and install a fresh copy of windows on C: cause if you install Windows on D: while keeping old windows on D: you will be having 2 Windows on your system and you will have to chose what OS to boot on every time you turn on your computer .

Note : System reserved is not a drive to install windows on it is usually created by windows when installing and its space is limited between 800 MB and 2-3 GB .

Best Regards.